# jQuery Validation multiple selectors for ignore

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am running into a problem with jQuery Validation and need to ignore some fields.

I need to ignore fields based on a class that I set and then also all hidden fields.  What I need to do is the following, but it is only honoring the second ignore.  I am assuming there is a way to tell jQuery Validation these multiple selectors but I cannot seem to find it.

```
validator = $("#form1").validate({
    onsubmit: false,
    ignore: ".ignore",
    ignore: ":hidden",
```

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the validation documentation:

> jQuery's not-method is used, therefore everything that is accepted by not() can be passed as this option.

Therefore all you need to do is pass one parameter with your selectors separated by commas:

```
validator = $("#form1").validate({
    onsubmit: false,
    ignore: ".ignore, :hidden"
});
```

Comment: Of course it would be that easy - hand to forehead... why didn't I just try that?  Thanks!

Comment: The documentation doesn't make this totally obvious – if you set `ignore: ".ignore"`, that _replaces_ the default of `ignore: ":hidden"`. So if you want the validation to ignore hidden fields like it does by default, _and_ ignore additional fields by class name or whatever, you have to chain the selectors as shown above.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using:

```
ignore: ".ignore, :hidden"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to all hidden fields:

```
$(":hidden").addClass('ignore');
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about that but didn't want to do that because then I would have to deal with removing/adding that class every time I wanted to show or hide elements.

Answer (score 0):

There also works double "not()". I.e:

```
ignore: ".ignore, :hidden:not(.required)"
```

This way some hidden fields that are required won't be ignored. Might be needed if someone uses dropdawn, and checkbox customization plugins.

Comment: Please check your grammar, and consider making this a comment, this is just an addition to an already existing answer.