# Ignoring required's on an entire form using jQuery.Validate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, html-helper

I'm trying to ignore the required validation on an entire form using jQuery validate but can't seem to get it working, this is on an MVC project using an @html helper so I can't add names to the elements to validate, I also cant remove the validation then add it all back using jQuery since not all the fields are required, I'll put my current java below and any help will be much appreciated

```js
$("body").on("click", ".next", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var btn = $(this);
  var form = btn.closest("form");
  form.validate({
    rules: {
      required: false
    }
  });
  //check if form is valid
  if (form.valid()) {
    var out = form.validate({
      rules: {
        required: true
      }
    });
    if (form.valid()) {
      alert("valid and complete");
    } else {
      alert("valid but not complete");
    }
  } else {
    showSysMessage("Invalid Data. Please Check the Data in the Highlighted Fields", {
      color: "#FFB347"
    });
  };
});
```

**Edit**

This validator needs to validate multiple different partials with over 300 fields so using the names of each individual element would be beyond impractical, so I'm wondering if there is a way to validate a form and not validate the required on the inputs, hope this helps

**Edit 2**

Im my model I have the fields that are required with a [Required] over them, But I would like stage one on the validation to check if the data entered is valid, If it is it will save these to the database and allow page change, then the second step of the validation needs to check if all the elements that have been set to required in the model have been filled in, and if they have been return that the form has been Completed

Here is a sample of my model

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public int? TitleID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Middle Names")]
    public string Middlename { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nationality")]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Martial Status")]
    public int? StatusMaritalID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "NI Number")]
    public string NINumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Have you been known by diffrent names?")]
    public bool? IsKnownByOtherNames { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Here is a sample of the controller that gets any filled out data

```
    model.TitleID = data.TitleID;

    model.FirstName = data.FirstName;

    model.Middlename = data.Middlename;

    model.Surname = data.Surname;

    model.DateOfBirth = data.DateOfBirth;

    model.Nationality = data.Nationality;

    model.StatusMaritalID = data.StatusMaritalID;

    model.NINumber = data.NINumber;

    model.IsKnownByOtherNames = data.IsKnownByOtherNames;

    model.PhoneNumber = data.PhoneNumber;

    model.MobileNumber = data.MobileNumber;

    model.Email = data.Email;
```

Here is an example of the save controller

```
                data.TitleID = model.TitleID;

                data.FirstName = model.FirstName;

                data.Middlename = model.Middlename;

                data.Surname = model.Surname;

                data.DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth;

                data.Nationality = model.Nationality;

                data.StatusMaritalID = model.StatusMaritalID;

                data.NINumber = model.NINumber;

                data.IsKnownByOtherNames = model.IsKnownByOtherNames;

                data.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;

                data.MobileNumber = model.MobileNumber;

                data.Email = model.Email;
```

Here is the view being used

```
<h2>Personal Details</h2>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TitleID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TitleID, Model.Titles, "-- Please Select --", new { @class = "input-block-level" })
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "input-block-level date-picker" })
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nationality)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nationality, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Middlename)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Middlename, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StatusMaritalID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StatusMaritalID, Model.StatusMaritals, "-- Please Select --", new { @class = "input-block-level" })
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Surname)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Surname, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NINumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NINumber, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
    </div>
</div>

<h3>Contact Details</h3>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MobileNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MobileNumber, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "input-block-level", type="email" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="checkbox span12" style="padding-left:0;">
        @Html.CheckBox("IsKnownByOtherNames", Model.IsKnownByOtherNames != null && (bool)Model.IsKnownByOtherNames)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsKnownByOtherNames)
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally here is my entire save script

```
$("body").on("click", ".next", function(e){
            debugger;
            e.preventDefault();
            var btn = $(this);
            var form = btn.closest("form");
            form.validate({
                rules: {
                    required: false
                }
            });
            //check if form is valid
            if (form.valid()) {
                var out = form.validate({
                    rules: {
                        required: true
                    }
                });
                if (form.valid()) { 
                    // disable the button to prevent multiple posts
                    btn.prop("disabled", true);
                    // serialise the form fields into an array
                    var fields = form.serializeArray();
                    // create a blank object to stuff the parameters into for the ajax call
                    var params = {};
                    // loop over the array and create a property for each item in array
                    // in the format expected by the controller action
                    $.each(fields, function (index, element) {
                        params[element.name] = element.value;
                    });
                    //loop over all checkboxes and see if they are checked or not
                    var checkboxes = form.find("input:checkbox")
                    $.each(checkboxes, function (index, element) {
                        params[element.name] = $(element).is(":checked");
                    });
                    // Make the ajax post call
                    // passing the parameters
                    $.post("UpdateCheck", params)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        alert("valid and complete");
                        // if fail alert the user of fail with error
                        if (data == false) {
                            //Create a toast message alerting of fail with reason
                            showSysMessage("Failed to Save. (Data Error)", { color: "#FFB347" });
                            // re-enables button
                            btn.prop("disabled", false);
                        } else {
                            btn.prop("disabled", false);
                            var currentpage = parseInt($(".TinyDancer").attr("data-currentpage"))
                            var newpage = currentpage + 1;
                            $.post("Page"+PageNos[newpage], {id:@Model.ID }).success(function(html){
                                $("#WizardStage").val(PageNos[newpage]);
                                $(".page[data-pageno='" + PageNos[newpage] + "']").parent().addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
                                $(".TinyDancer").slideUp(function(){$(".TinyDancer").html(html).promise().done(function() {$(".TinyDancer").slideDown();});});
                                $(".TinyDancer").attr("data-currentpage", newpage);
                                $("form").removeData("validator");
                                $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
                            });
                        }
                    }).fail(function () {
                        showSysMessage("Failed to Save. (Network Transport Error))", { color: "#FFB347" });
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("valid but not complete");}
            }else{
                showSysMessage("Invalid Data. Please Check the Data in the Highlighted Fields", { color: "#FFB347" });
            };
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean _I can't add names to the elements to validate_ - if your using the `HtmlHelper` methods, then `name` attributes are already added. Its not clear what your trying to do. Are you just wanting to ignore client side validation based on some condition?

Comment: This validator needs to validate multiple different partials with over 300 fields so using the names of each individual element would be beyond impractical, so I'm wondering if there is a way to validate a form and not validate the required on the inputs, hope this helps, I'll append this to the bottom of the question for others, cheers

Comment: But why are you not just using `jqueryvalidate.unobtrusive.js` and the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` methods Buts its still not clear. Are you wanting to exclude just certain items (in which case you could give them a class name (say `class="ignore"`) and configure the validator to ignore all elements with that class name.

Comment: I should have mentioned the project that I'm working on does use jqueryvalidate.unobtrusive.js. Also I should have mentions the idea behind the validation is to not outright ignore elements but just don't check if they are required hence the two steps of validation, if you can provide a solution that allows me to add a class to an element and ignore the required's I will be more than happy to use that, Thanks again

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050591/jquery-validation-multiple-selectors-for-ignore) shows an example (bit its still unclear what your trying to achieve here, and if that is really the right solution for you)

Comment: That is a blanket ignore, not ignore the required part of the validation, It needs to still check if they for example put a string in an int input to prevent database crashes/errors??

Comment: I'm guessing that the fact you have `.on("click", ".next",` suggests you might be some kind of wizard and are wanting to validate each step, one at a time. If that is the case, then refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Comment: Your last comment still does not make sense. If you have an `int` property and want to allow `null` (not required) values, but ensure that if a value is entered it is a valid `int` then the the property needs to be `int?` (nullable), not `int` (and without a `[Required]` attribute)

Comment: I should have used the word number, Im my model I have the fields that are required with a [Required] over them, But I would like stage one on the validation to check if the data entered is valid, If it is it will save these to the database and allow page change, then the second step of the validation needs to check if all the elements that have been set to required in the model have been filled in, and if they have been return that the form has been Completed, I shall also add this to an edit along with a sample of my model and view

Comment: Then your should be using 2 different view models, one for the first stage of validation and another for the second stage.

Comment: How can I validate using two entire models on one page, last time I check @Html helpers bind to a model when they are created and this model then cannot be changed??

Comment: But your last comment stated _will save these to the database and **allow page change**_ which I assume you mean redirects to another page

Comment: Please take the term allow page change loosely, It actually loads a new partial and replaces the content of my div called .TinyDancer as can be seen in edit2

Comment: Well you can start by deleting a whole lot of code and use `$.post("UpdateCheck", $('form').serialize())`. But you calling a method that returns a partial view so that partial can be based on the second view model which does include `[Required]` attributes. (need some sleep now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke for pointing me in the right direction for this one, I have finally come up with a fully dynamic solution which should work for every single field without requiring separate pages/partials or models.

To do this Firstly at the point you load your page/partial run this script to add a class called isRequired to all of the required elements

```
var fields = $("form").find("input[data-val]");
$.each(fields, function (index, element) {
    $(element).addClass("isRequired")
});
```

Thee next thing do do is to format the validation script like so

```
$("body").on("click", ".next", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this);
    var form = btn.closest("form");

    $.each($('.isRequired'), function (index, element) {
        $(element).rules('add', {
            required: false   // set a new rule
        });
    });

    form.validate();
    //check if form is valid
    if (form.valid()) {
        $.each($('.isRequired'), function (index, element) {
            $(element).rules('add', {
                required: true   // set a new rule
            });
        });
        form.validate();
        if (form.valid()) { 
            alert("Form is Completed and Valid")
        } else {
            alert("Form is Valid but not complete");}
    }else{
        alert("Data Enter in some of the fields is of an Invalid Type")
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

by default MVC put the property name as the name of the input and add required by default in value types, I don't know about your view model, maybe you have a value type field that isn't required in this case make it nullable resolve

Comment: All fields are nullable in my model, please check edit, Thanks