# jquery validation ignore and include

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form with large set of fields that includes both read only and hidden fields. I want to **enable** validation for **hidden** field but disable validation for **ready only** fields

In the new version of jQuery validation plugin by the default validation of hidden fields are ignored. So to enable it I have to use :

```js
$("form[name='Formname']").validate({
 ignore: []
});
```

and it is working fine. But I need to ignore the validation for readonly fields and for that I need to use

```js
$("form[name='Formname']").validate({
 ignore: [readonly=readonly]
});
```

Even if i merge the two,it still doesn't work because than it only ignore readonly but doesn't apply vaildation on hidden field

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050591/jquery-validation-multiple-selectors-for-ignore

Comment: Did you try passing it as a string? `'[readonly="readonly"]'`

Comment: @mplungjan No, he wants validation for hidden fields.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741175/295783

Comment: @Arg0n yes i have tried but it is only working for readonly case then

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass selector to [ignore](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) like this

`ignore: '[readonly]', // This will select all input with readonly and ignore`

> Elements to ignore when validating, simply filtering them out.
>   jQuery's not-method is used, therefore everything that is accepted by
>   not() can be passed as this option. Inputs of type submit and reset
>   are always ignored, so are disabled elements.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$("form[name='Formname']").validate({
 ignore: '[readonly]',
 rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    },
    field1: {
      required: true
    }} 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form name="Formname">

<input readonly name="field1">
<input type="text" id="field" name="field">

<input type="submit" value="Validate!">

</form>
```